# How to make MySQL join one-to-many with lowest value?

Tags: mysql

I have following database structure

[image: Schema]

`Domain` has many URL which has many `positions` which belongs to `phrase` which belongs to `user` which belongs to `subscription`.

In `subscriptions` table I have `period` field and I need to fetch all `domains` with lowest `period` value from `subscriptions`. To accomplish this challenge I've created following query

```
 select
        domains.domain,
        domains.id,
        subscriptions.period

        from
            domains
        inner join urls ON urls.domain_id = domains.id
        inner join positions ON positions.url_id = urls.id
        inner join phrases ON phrases.id = positions.phrase_id
        inner join users ON users.id = phrases.user_id
        inner join subscriptions ON subscriptions.id = users.subscription_id
```

Which return me results similar to

```
"domain": "http://www.example.com",
"id":     60,
"period": 7

"domain": "http://www.example.com",
"id":     60,
"period": 30

"domain": "http://www.other-example.com",
"id":     61,
"period": 7
```

In the results one of the domains occurs more than on time, because two different user with varied subscription have the same domain.

How can I filter results and get only lowest `period` value for given domain?

```
"domain": "http://www.example.com",
"id":     60,
"period": 7

"domain": "http://www.other-example.com",
"id":     61,
"period": 7
```

Comment: `GROUP BY domains.id, domains.domain` and use `MIN(subscriptions.period)` in the Select?

Comment: It is not going to work fine. It will return one record. I will attach jsfiddle in a flash.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Yes, mon faux pas. It works. You can write below your answer to clarify it to others.

Comment: Helid - why don't you add an answer with the changes suggested by @ypercube - you can show the exact query that worked for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested @ypercube it can be done by grouping by `domains.id, domains.domain` and `selecting min(subscriptions.period)`. Complete query:

```
 select
        domains.domain,
        domains.id,
        MIN(subscriptions.period) as period

        from
            domains
        inner join urls ON urls.domain_id = domains.id
        inner join positions ON positions.url_id = urls.id
        inner join phrases ON phrases.id = positions.phrase_id
        inner join users ON users.id = phrases.user_id
        inner join subscriptions ON subscriptions.id = users.subscription_id

        GROUP BY domains.id
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/438c1/2